# How do I efficiently inverse a many-to-many SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a many-to-many relationship, in which I query **all M which have a specific N**, for example:

```
SELECT M.* FROM M INNER JOIN ManyToManyTable
ON M.Id = ManyToManyTable.M
WHERE ManyToManyTable.N = @Id
```

Or:

```
SELECT M.* FROM M INNER JOIN ManyToManyTable
ON M.Id = ManyToManyTable.M
INNER JOIN N
ON N.Id = ManyToManyTable.N
WHERE N.Id = @Id
```

My question is, how to efficiently inverse the query so I get *all M which **do not have** a specific N*?

That is, like a `NOT IN` the selects above, but without the `NOT IN` statement, if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server 'NOT EXISTS' is generally [more efficient](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/) than the OUTER JOIN approach.

```
SELECT M.* FROM M  
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT * FROM ManyToManyTable MMT
           WHERE MMT.M = M.Id AND N=@Id )
```

Comment: Took me a while to fit my exact needs (that is-- translate to NHibernate), but works beautifully! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty:

```
SELECT M.* FROM M
WHERE M.id NOT IN
    (SELECT M.id FROM M INNER JOIN ManyToManyTable
     ON M.Id = ManyToManyTable.M
     WHERE ManyToManyTable.N = @Id)
```

Better:

```
SELECT M.*
FROM M LEFT JOIN ManyToManyTable
ON M.Id = ManyToManyTable.M
WHERE ManyToManyTable.M IS NULL
```